# How can I include tags in wordpress search without a plugin

Tags: php, functions, search

I`m using the [Search Everything plugin](https://pt.wordpress.org/plugins/search-everything/) to enhance my wordpress search mostly because I need to include some custom fields and tags in search results. It works great, but...

The first problem with this plugin is that it makes the user select all (Search every custom field) custom fields when I just include relevant data in one or two. The practical result of this is that it makes wordpress search incredibly slow.

The second problem is that I also like to include tags on search, but I have no option to select only the relevant custom fields and tags in the wordpress search?

Is there a way to force wordpress search to include tags on wordpress search without a plugin?

Comment: Yes.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page  and https://www.rfmeier.net/include-category-and-post-tag-names-in-the-wordpress-search/ should help

Comment: Changing the search behavior is pure plugin territory. There is no other clean way than writing or finding a proper plugin for that.

Comment: @fuxia is there any plugin that allows to choose the relevant search fields and includes tags in search? The reason why I'm asking is because search all custom fields is counter-productive and it makes the search too slow.

Comment: I bet there is one. But you can also write your own plugin and filter the search query for specific taxonomies. That would be more fun, and you might learn something. :)